# Which FHIR resource do I need to use?

Tags: hl7-fhir, medical, hapi-fhir

I am developing a dialysis app and need to store a diagnosis to display into a table as shown in the attached image. Can anyone provide guidance on which R4 FHIR resources to use for this? Thank you.

I've looked into the FHIR docs and I am still uncertain whether I should use CarePlan or Condition. Your help is very much appreciated.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUmBk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarePlan seems like a good fit.

- Renal Diagnosis - CarePlan.addresses
- Other medical history - CarePlan.supportingInfo
- Treatment strategy & goals - CarePlan.detail.code.text
- Target BP - CarePlan.goal
- Updated on - Provenance
- Updated by - Provenance

Comment: yeah, that should be it. i will proceed with this answer. Thank you Lloyd.